# How do I automatically update dependent variables in R

Tags: r

I have an input variable which I want to use for referencing another variable from a data frame, but when I change the input variable, the output reference doesn't automatically update

```
head(gilt_val)

  col_names    curve
1       0.5 1.000000
2       1.0 1.004912
3       1.5 1.004309
4       2.0 1.003908
5       2.5 1.003606
6       3.0 1.003506


x = 1

spot_duration = ifelse(x>0, gilt_val$curve[match(x, gilt_val$col_names)], 0)

spot_duration
#[1] 1.004912

x = 2
spot_duration
#[1] 1.004912
```

Clearly I want the updated spot_duration to read 1.003908 without having to re-enter the equation ever time. Is this possible? Many thanks

Comment: I couldn't get the data frame to sit properly on this site so I have typed it out to make it look more presentable

Answer (score 4):

You may want to write a function of `x`.

```
spot_duration <- function(x) ifelse(x > 0, gilt_val$curve[match(x, gilt_val$col_names)], 0)
spot_duration(x=1)
# [1] 1.004912
spot_duration(x=2)
# [1] 1.003908
```

#### Data

```
gilt_val <- structure(list(col_names = c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3), curve = c(1, 
1.004912, 1.004309, 1.003908, 1.003606, 1.003506)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `function` as @jay.sf has already ponted out. To call it without brackets have a look at [R functions without brackets](https://medium.com/@davidhughjones/r-functions-without-brackets-2052bb7ee396).

```
print.command <- function (cmd) {
  default.args <- attr(cmd, "default.args")
  if (length(default.args) == 0L) default.args <- list()
  res <- do.call(cmd, default.args, envir = parent.frame(2))
  if (attr(cmd, "print_result")) print(res)
  invisible(NULL)
}

make_command <- function(x, ..., print = TRUE) {
  class(x) <- c("command", class(x))
  attr(x, "default.args") <- list(...)
  attr(x, "print_result") <- print
  x
}

fun  <- function() {ifelse(x>0, gilt_val$curve[match(x, gilt_val$col_names)], 0)}

spot_duration <- make_command(fun)

x  <-  1
spot_duration
#[1] 1.004912

x  <-  2
spot_duration
#[1] 1.003908
```

Data:

```
gilt_val <- structure(list(col_names = c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3), curve = c(1, 
1.004912, 1.004309, 1.003908, 1.003606, 1.003506)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```